# Change in Variables applied to biharmonic equation

Tags: pde, boundary-conditions, computational-geometry, numerical-modelling

### Background

I want to solve the following [biharmonic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation):

$$\frac{ \partial^4 s }{ {\partial \xi}^4 }+\frac{ \partial^4 s }{ {\partial \xi}^2{\partial t}^2 }+\frac{ \partial^4 s }{ {\partial t}^4 }=0\label{1}\tag{1}$$

on the unit square with the four Edges E1, E2, E3, and E4 (Fig. 1 left) and its prescribed boundary conditions (Fig. 1 right). The values of the boundary conditions
$\frac{ \partial \xi }{ {\partial s} }\bigg\rvert_{E1}$ and $\frac{ \partial \xi }{ {\partial s} }\bigg\rvert_{E2}$ can be set by me arbitrarily.

[image: Unit square with labeled edges, boundary conditions for PDE]

Additionally, $s$=$s$($\xi$,t) is known and is plotted in (Fig. 2).

[image: Known solution s of PDE]

Although the data in (fig.2) lies in the space s($\xi$,t), like the solution of Eq \eqref{1}, it's not the desired solution of Eq \eqref{1}. It is the starting point for further consideration, which becomes clear immediately.

### Problem

Now I am going to quote the **actual task**, which I am struggling with:

> ... is solved by applying a **change in variables**. In fact we solve $\Delta\Delta$ $f$= 0 where $f$: $s$ $\in$ [0,1] $\mapsto$ [0,1] is a monotonic functions whichs maps a unit inverval onto a unit interval. The boundary conditions for $s$ are transferred to corresponding boundary conditions for $f$. After solving $\Delta\Delta$ $f$= 0, we find $f$ values at interior grid points and the corresponding $s$ values are found using $f^{-1}$. In practice, we define $f$: $s$ $\in$ [0,1] $\mapsto$ [0,1] such that $f$(0.5$\times$($s_{E3}(\xi)$+$s_{E4}(\xi)$)) $\equiv$ $\xi$

(Source: S. P. Spekreijse "Elliptic generation Systems", page 19; 1997) https://reports.nlr.nl/bitstream/handle/10921/1402/TP-1996-735.pdf?sequence=1)

### Attempted solution

In the following, I want to show you how I understand the **change in variables**, what my approach is and which detail I don't grasp. If anything along the way is wrong, let me know, please! I am an engineer and my mathematical understanding is limited. Thus, some steps might be right, but it might also be the case, that everything is just wrong.

---

I am supposed to transform (Eq. 1) into:

$$\frac{ \partial^4 f }{ {\partial s}^4 }+\frac{ \partial^4 f }{ {\partial s}^2{\partial t}^2 }+\frac{ \partial^4 f }{ {\partial t}^4 }=0\label{2}\tag{2}$$

or

$$\frac{ \partial^4 \xi }{ {\partial s}^4 }+\frac{ \partial^4 \xi }{ {\partial s}^2{\partial t}^2 }+\frac{ \partial^4 \xi }{ {\partial t}^4 }=0\label{3}\tag{3}$$

(Eq. 2) and (Eq. 3) are the same because in the quoted task the relation $f$(0.5$\times$($s_{E3}(\xi)$+$s_{E4}(\xi)$)) $\equiv$ $\xi$ is defined, which implies $f$ $\equiv$ $\xi$. This change in variable is illustrated in (fig 3.).

[image]

In order to solve (Eq. 3) the boundary conditions in (fig. 1 right or rewritten in fig. 4 left ) are to be transformed from the space $s=s(\xi,t)$ to the space $\xi=\xi(s,t)$. This transformation is shown in (fig. 4).

[image]

Once this transformation has been completed, we have a boundary value problem with prescribed boundary conditions. By applying "fast Fourier transformation" or the "general coupled approach for biharmonic functions" this boundary value problem can be solved.

I have calculated the transformed values for $\xi$ from the the given relation $f$(0.5$\times$($s_{E3}(\xi)$+$s_{E4}(\xi)$)) $\equiv$ $\xi$.

Looking at at the boundary conditions in (fig. 4), I don't know how I can deduce the normal derivatives (Neumann Boundary Conditions) in (fig. 4 right), i.e.:

$$\frac{ \partial \xi }{ {\partial s} }\bigg\rvert_{E1}, \frac{ \partial \xi }{ {\partial s} }\bigg\rvert_{E2} \quad\mathrm{and}\quad \frac{ \partial \xi }{ {\partial t} }\bigg\rvert_{E3}, \frac{ \partial \xi }{ {\partial t} }\bigg\rvert_{E4}$$

from

$$\frac{ \partial s }{ {\partial \xi} }\bigg\rvert_{E1}, \frac{ \partial s }{ {\partial \xi} }\bigg\rvert_{E2} \quad\mathrm{and}\quad \frac{ \partial s }{ {\partial t} }\bigg\rvert_{E3}=0, \frac{ \partial s }{ {\partial t} }\bigg\rvert_{E4}=0$$

in (fig. 4 left).

I believe I can solve (Eq. 3) once I know the answer to this question.

Comment: @Tyberius: thank you for correcting my post